# Proving an object is terminal given that the object has a unique global element

Tags: category-theory

A global element of an object $a$ is a morphism $1 \rightarrow a$ where $1$ is a terminal object. If the object $c$ in a Category has a unique global element, can we prove that $c$ is a terminal object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. For example, in the category of groups, every object has a unique global element.

Comment: Thanks for the example! If we restrict ourselves to only talking about the category of set, then it would be a terminal object, right?

Comment: Yes, in the category of Sets, there is a canonical bijection between the global elements of a set $X$ and the actual elements of $X$. So a set with a unique global element is a singleton set, which is always terminal.

Comment: Got it! Thanks for the clear explanation.